# Rails routes syntax - from rails 2 to rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm following a tutorial (the learning rails podcast) and need to change the following route syntax so that it's compatible with Rails 3.0. can anyone help?

```
map.view_page ':name', :controller => 'viewer', :action => 'show'
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you generate a new Rails 3 app, the boilerplate `routes.rb` has some decent examples in it, including this one.

```
# Sample of named route:
#   match 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', :as => :purchase
# This route can be invoked with purchase_url(:id => product.id)
```

Given what you have above, this would translate to the following.

```
match ':name' => 'viewer#show', :as => :view_page
```

If you check this with `rake routes` you'll see this.

```
$ rake routes
view_page  /:name(.:format) {:controller=>"viewer", :action=>"show"}
```

Comment: thanks. I was trying something similar to that but couldn't get the syntax right. thanks for the help